# Incorrect DateTime Value When Loading CSV With CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to load a CSV file with timestamp values in one column using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). The file is parsed and `GetRecords()` executes but the output records contain `0001-01-01T00:00:00` for the `DateTime` values, which is definitely not what was in the input.

I created a `CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<MyClass>` to assist in the parsing of the input timestamp values and register it in the configuration, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
List<MyClass> records = new List<MyClass>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader("/path/to/file"))
{
  using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
  {
    csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
    csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();
    records.AddRange(csvReader.GetRecords<MyClass>());
  }
}

public sealed class CsvMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<MyClass>
{
  public CsvMap()
  {
    string format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    var enUS = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption.Format(format)
      .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(enUS);
  }
}

public class MyClass
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The input CSV file contains timestamps in the format `2006-10-01 00:00:00` which I believe matches the format specified in the `CsvMap` class (`"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`). However, all dates output from `CsvHelper` are `0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to change it to  string format = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss";

Comment: Unrelated: `hh` denotes 12 hour time with an am/pm and `HH` is 24 hour time.

Comment: I do not think the issue is with your format as `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2006-10-01 00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));` works as expected. Please include an [mcve] as well as the actual content of your CSV file in the question.

Comment: Upon further review, @Igor is correct. The issue was with an object to DTO transformation, not `CsvHelper`. Thank you, @Igor!